# What could be the reason for error "message":"Undefined index: jwt"?

Tags: php, google-oauth

For my online platform, I'm setting up a basic google sign-in button whereby users can create an account or log-in using their gmail email address.
I created my **credentials**: OAuth 2.0 Client IDs (got both ID and secret) and Service Accounts (now removed - not needed when asking access approval from user).
For the **oauth consent screen**, I've added my non-sensitive scopes:

```
./auth/userinfo.email
./auth/userinfo.profile
openid
```

I'm using my own gmail address for testing and API url used is `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?` with query on the `email` field.

EDIT: I've removed the service account so ignore this:
I have setup my jwt sign too with the service account email (XXX-googleconnect@genial-analyzer-341XXX...) and the (pretty damn long) generated key.

Could you please tell me how to debug the error "message":"Undefined index: jwt" when I run the google API?

EDIT: I've amended my code to reflect the removal of the service account. So no more jwt token: `"jwt_bearer": "false",`

```
<?php
$exports = <<<'JSON'
{
  "name": "oauth",
  "module": "oauth",
  "action": "provider",
  "options": {
    "jwt_bearer": "false",
    "service": "google",
    "client_id": "307540412021-test06test06test06test06test06.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "XXXXX-X0RMDgT1nEgxAKrOmpcjK4sXY7Qq",
    "tokenHandling": "self"
  },
  "meta": [
    {
      "name": "access_token",
      "type": "text"
    }
  ],
  "outputType": "object"
}
JSON;
?>
```

But now I get `"message":"Undefined index: false",`

*Disclaimer: I'm a no-coder, with basic php knowledge, pls if you could possibly use as easy to understand a language, that would be highly appreciated (and helpful for other no-coders too I bet)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to understand is that there is a big diffrence between Service account authoirzation, Oauth2, and signin.

If you run oauth2 authorization and request access of the using the email and profile scopes your going to have access to the users profile information.

if you try to run service account authentication and request the email and profile scopes your either going to get an error or your going to get the service accounts profile information.  As a service account is a dummy user.

> "message":"Undefined index: jwt"

Implies to me that you are using the wrong code for the wrong client.

## service account client credentils

```
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

## Oauth2 client

```
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}
```

As you can see the code is completely different for each type of authorization.

My main issue is why are you even trying to mix service account authorization into this if you are signing users into your app?

- [Should you be using a Google service account?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTTTtwb7x7g&t=1s)

Comment: Thank you, the video is great. If I understand well, since we ask for user permission to access his/her email, no need for service account.
Now I wish I could share a reproducible example but i use a php-based no code framework... Yet do you mind if I include a few lines of code in my question?

Comment: No you have no need for a service account.  service accounts are only intended for use with accounts you the developer control.    If you are just after user profile info then you should go though the Google people api and check out the google api php client library

Comment: Dear, where can I find the correct, up-to-date google oauth2 API url?
My fields query on 'given_name', 'family_name' or 'name' at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo does not return a first and last name, but NULL.

Comment: I would go though the [Google People api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) and not though the userinfo endpoint.   remember the user must have added their name to their profile if they havent then your not going to get anything back.

Comment: Got it, will try the people.get method.
Although I've tested the oauth2 API with **my own profile which does have a first and last name** and email of course yet nothing was returned in the response. I've fetched its schema and got [family_name, name, picture, email, given_name, id among other things] in the data object. Is this API being deprecated? Or else it should return something!
Will report if any issue. Thanks